# Need callback returns multiple values in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want muliple values in my callback function

> ```
> myfunction(i,function(err,result){
>   console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(result)));   
>  ****//i need value here..****
>
>
> });
> ```

```
function myfunction(i,callback) {
/* my some stuff */
var callBackString= new Array();
                        callBackString['value1']=value1;
                        callBackString['value2']= value2;
                        callBackString['value3']= value3;
                        callback(null,callBackString);

};
```

I am returting callBackString as an array..,

Can anybody tell me how to do that

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I am not able to get returned values

Comment: Try to use `var callBackString = {}`. You are using your array like an object, so make it one. When you serialize the array with `JSON.stringify()` those non-array properties get lost.

Comment: Typo at `stringify`? You omitted an `n` there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an object instead:

```
function myfunction(i, callback) {
  var callBackString = {};
  callBackString.value1 = value1;
  callBackString.value2 = value2;
  callBackString.value3 = value3;
  callback(null, callBackString);
}
```

Then the receiving end:

```
myfunction(i, function(err, result) {
  var value1 = result.value1;
  var value2 = result.value2;
  var value3 = result.value3;

  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(result)));   
});
```

Comment: The last line in the callback is unnecessary. If you want to make a copy of the data, it should be the first there.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
function myfunction(i, callback) {
  // ...
  // Returns an Array
  return callback(null, [value1, value2, value3])
}

function myfunction2(i, callback) {
  // ...
  // Returns an Object
  return callback(null, {value1: value1, value2: value2, value3: value3})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Hope it works

```
myfunction(i,function(err,value1,value2,value3){
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(result)));   
 ****//i need value here..****


});


function myfunction(i,callback) {
/* my some stuff */
var callBackString= new Array();
                        callBackString['value1']=value1;
                        callBackString['value2']= value2;
                        callBackString['value3']= value3;
                        callback(null,value1,value2,value3);

};
```